# Is there a way to capture the emails entered in comments section into aweber list

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way to capture the emails which are entered while commenting on the wordpress blog and adding them to aweber list?

Better is there a plugin which could do the same?

Thanks
Prady

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run a MySQL query on the wp_comments table like...

```
SELECT DISTINCT comment_author_email FROM `wp_comments`;
```

...But please realize that unless your commenters have specifically opted in and are aware that they're going to be added to a list, they may get really annoyed as what you're doing is tantamount to spam. :|

Comment: The proper way to handle this would be to force the user to sign up to the site in order to comment and have a box ticked on the signup form saying they want to receive news and updates.